# Как передать в объект значения атрибута другого объекта? (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom

Хороший человек подарил мне хороший скрипт, так как в DOM и JavaScript я не силён.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRadioName(){

var cont = document.getElementById('radio_name');
cont.onclick = function (event) {
document.getElementById("div_text").innerHTML = document.getElementById(event.target.id).innerHTML;
//alert("Вы ткнули по "+document.getElementById(event.target.id).innerHTML);
}

}
</script>

<!-- описание -->
<!-- Скрипт передаёт в объект внутренний код HTML -->

<!-- применение -->
<h4 id="2" onClick="getRadioName()">Dfm (Москва)</h4>
```

Вопрос:
Как применить\переработать его на передачу значения атрибута объекта?
Допустим для атрибута alt?

```
<img src="http://kansk-land.ru/radio_files/Dfm-Moskva.jpg" alt="Dfm (Москва)" id="2" onClick="getRadioName()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт! (Оставлю. Может пригодится кому-то)

```
document.getElementById(event.target.id).alt
```

Dreamweaver сам подсказал!